# Get the href attribute for each link in a section of HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written the following jQuery to loop through each of the `<a>` objects in a section of HTML:

```
$(".chapterindex" + key + " div.link a").each(function(intIndex){
  alert("Numbered index: " + intIndex);
});
});
```

The key value used in the first line of the jQuery is from an array of URL's I've built manually, something like this:

```
var chapters = new Array();
chapters[0] = "original/html/0/ID0EFJAE.html";
```

I can alert the `intIndex` which gives me, `0,1,2,3,4,5....` etc..

But how can I extend the jQuery above to get the `href` attribute from each of the links found in the HTML?

Comment: Hungarian Notation so needs to die...

Comment: Hungarian Notation is misunderstood and very misused.  The prefix was never meant to annotate data type - it was supposed to suggest the usage of the variable.  Unfortunately, all you see nowadays is the malformed version of the notation. ;(  +1

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$(".chapterindex" + key + " div.link a").each(

    function(intIndex){
        alert( "Numbered index: " + intIndex );

        var href = $(this).attr('href');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access it through `$(this).attr('href')`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".chapterindex" + key + " div.link a").each(

    function(intIndex){
        alert( "Numbered index: " + $(this).attr("href") );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".chapterindex" + key + " div.link a").each(function () {
  alert(this.href);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the full HREF or the HREF as it appears in the tag?

The jQuery object method `$(this).attr('href')` proposed by some people will return whatever is set as the HREF attribute in the tag.

The DOM node property method `this.href` proposed by John will return the fully-qualified URL.

So given a link `<a href="/resources/foo.ext">Foo</a>`, the jQuery method will return "/resources/foo.ext" while the other method will return "http://mysite.ca/currentpath/resources/foo.ext".

So it just depends on what you need returned.

Comment: well not currentpath, since it is a root path, if it was only resources/foo.ext, then yes.

Comment: My gosh... if I had said "the current path" rather than "the full HREF" in the actual description (rather than just something thrown without thought into the fake URL) it would've been worth correcting. ;-)