# How to get all href attributes values of <a>

Tags: jquery, html

How to get all href attributes values of

```
<ul>
   <li class="demo">
        <a href="/chat/2"></a>
   </li>
   <li class="demo">
        <a href="/chat/3"></a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

How can I get Href attributes values in one array?

Comment: Looks like a dupe of several other questions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759823/jquery-get-the-href-attribute-for-each-link-in-a-section-of-html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471606/get-all-hrefs-as-an-array-in-jquery
And several others.

Comment: Note that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14359001/519413) in the marked duplicate is the best one as it uses `map()`, not the one with the highest votes.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Arr=[];
$("li.demo").each(function(){
 Arr.push($(this).find("a").attr("href")); 
});
console.log(Arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li class="demo">
        <a href="/chat/2"></a>
   </li>
   <li class="demo">
        <a href="/chat/3"></a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: if it is useful please checked confirm for help others

Answer (score -1):

```js
let foo = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
console.log(foo)
let my_array = [];

for(let i=0;i<foo.length;i++) {
  my_array.push(foo.item(i).href);
}

console.log(my_array)
```

```html
<ul>
   <li class="demo">
        <a href="/chat/2"></a>
   </li>
   <li class="demo">
        <a href="/chat/3"></a>
   </li>
</ul>
```